# COM - use IEnumerable in C++

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to expose a method which returns IEnumerable, but I am not able to consume it through C++ code. I read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399447/com-use-ienumerable-in-atl-c-project#7400109) question but it's about `IEnumerator` not `IEnumerable`.

```cs
[ComVisible(true),
    Guid("myguid")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IDbReader
{
    IEnumerable GetUsers();
}

[ComVisible(true),
    Guid("myguid2")]
[ProgId("MyDbReader.DbReader")]
internal class DbReader : IDbReader
{
    IEnumerable GetUsers() => new List<string>() { "User1", "User2" };
}
```

in C++:

```cpp
#import "MyDbReader.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

...

CComPtr<IDbReader> myreader; // created through a factory
CComPtr<IEnumerable> users;
myreader->GetUsers(&users);

users->GetEnumerator(); // The compiler says: pointer to incomplete class is not allowed
```

In addition, the compiler sees `IDbReader::IEnumerable` instead of using the standard `IEnumerable`.

what am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear how you arrived at that C++ code, you'd normally use the #import directive to import the type library generated by the C# project.  Which ought to resemble:

```
#import "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb"
using namespace mscorlib;
#import "CSharpLibrary.tlb"
using namespace CSharpLibrary;
```

Assuming the C# project name is "CSharpLibrary".  This generates smart pointer types derived from `_com_ptr_t`, they have the same name as the interface with `Ptr` appended.  With the advantage that reference counting is taken care of and that interface function call failure is reported with a C++ exception instead of a hard-to-deal-with HRESULT error code.

The additional detail, and indeed pretty hard to diagnose from the wonky compile error message but visible from IntelliSense, is that the .NET type library exporter translates System.Collections.IEnumerator to IEnumVARIANT*.  So basic code should look like:

```
try {
    IEnumerablePtr users = myreader->GetUsers();
    IEnumVARIANTPtr enumusers = users->GetEnumerator();
    _variant_t vuser;
    while (SUCCEEDED(enumusers->Next(1, &vuser, NULL))) {
        BSTR user = vuser.bstrVal;
        // etc...
    }
}
catch (_com_error& ex) {
    // Handle or report runtime error...
}
```

Untested, ought to be in the ballpark.  You can avoid the extra call to GetEnumerator() by having the C# interface expose IEnumerator instead of IEnumerable, as noted in the linked question.  You can read more about the C++ compiler support classes being used here in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use `#import "CSharpLibrary.tlb"  named_guids raw_interfaces_only` directive (without the flag I had >60 errors). In this way smart pointers are not generated, but you can still use CComPtr<IEnumerable> etc. I'll update the question.

Comment: BTW I was missing the `using namespace mscorlib;` and for whatever reason it was not working. This is a weird error message which doesn't help the user to fix the problem. Marking this as answer

Comment: Hmya, this is the kind of downward spiral you can end up in when the compile errors are not clear.  And you had more than one mistake, makes it extra convoluted.  You don't need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `DbReader.GetUsers(...)` implementation public so that it properly implements the `IDbReader` interface.  For example:

```
internal class DbReader : IDbReader
{
    public IEnumerable GetUsers() => new List<string>() { "User1", "User2" };
}
```

Also make sure that you are `using System.Collections` (for `IEnumerable`) in addition to `using System.Collections.Generic` (for `List<T>`) in the C# code.